# Query for created articles for all months of selected year for all users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I stuck with this,
 i have a table of articles which have updated_at and updated_by. I need to write query which will give me count of updated articles per user for all months of selected year.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*Here, I have taken 2016 as the year and assumed you have `current_user` available to you*

```
current_user.articles.where("extract(year from updated_at)= ?", 2016).count
```

Comment: Many users can create articles, i need count for all of them and i need data per month, not per year

Comment: @BozidarMilivojevic - You need a clearer definition of "per user".  If you have 3000 users, but only 2000 of them create/update an article, what result do you want?  `updates per user` = `total updates / 3000` *(because you have 3000 users)* or `total_updates / 2000` *(because you have 2000 users that made an update)*?

Comment: I want to see how much articles each user created for each month of selected year, i am passing only their ids to controller. If there is no updated articles for user, then its 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way:

```
Article.group("updated_by, date_trunc('month', updated_at)").where("extract(year from updated_at)= ?", 2016).count
```

It returns you result like `[updated_by, Month_NO] => count`